# Failed to download symfony/icu from dist: You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https Now trying to download from source

Tags: php, symfony

i have got this error while installing composer even after adding "extension=php_openssl.dll" to the php.ini file.. Please suggest me some way to get rid of this error. thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you add it to the right php.ini, the one used for CLI?

Comment: Please check which PHP version and php.ini is used for the CLI and apache, these are most likely different.